# How to compare actual and expected values in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Html code

```
<p><span class="ng-binding">displaying 15</span> of <span class="ng-binding">24</span></p>
```

If "Displaying 15 of 24" is displayed then i have to show test is passed.

Please please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the `p` element and check the text and displayedness:

```
var p = element(by.tagName("p"));  // probably a more precise and distinct locator should be used instead

expect(p.getText()).toEqual("Displaying 15 of 24");
expect(p.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```